# Trouble with game over screen for Python game with Pygame

Tags: python, function, while-loop, pygame

I wrote code for a basic snake game using the pygame module in python and have come to the point where I am basically done, however, I wish there to be a game over screen at the end that displays some text, gives the option to play again and displays the score. If they restart the score resets to 0 and they play again. Unfortunately I cannot seem to get this screen to run successfully. I have tried a couple of things yet I always seem to get the error that display Surface quit. I will share my code below if there are any tips.

```
import sys, time, random, pygame
from random import randrange
pygame.init()
fps_controller = pygame.time.Clock()
#Screen Dimensions
screen_width = 600
screen_height = 600

#Screen Set Up
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake by Bela Zumbansen")
pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)

#Colours
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLACK  = (0, 0, 0)
GREY = (200, 200, 200)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
LIGHTBLUE = (0, 155, 155)

#Directions
RIGHT = 1
LEFT = 2
UP = 3
DOWN = 4

#Game Set Up
snake_pos = [100, 100]
snake_body = [[100, 100], [90, 100], [80, 100]]
snake_speed = 10

apple_pos = [random.randrange(1,60)*10, random.randrange(1,60)*10]
apple_spawn = True

direction = RIGHT
update = direction

scoreval = 0

def game_over():
    global run, scoreval
    screen.fill(LIGHTBLUE)
    draw_text("GAME OVER", 48, WHITE, screen_width/2, screen_height/4)
    draw_text("Score: " + str(score), 22, WHITE,  screen_width / 2, screen_height / 3)
    draw_text("Press SPACE to play again or ESC to exit", 22, WHITE, screen_width/2, screen_height / 4)
    waiting = True
    while waiting:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    scoreval = 0
                    return scoreval
                    run = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
            return run
def draw_text(text, size, color, x, y):
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', size)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, font, color)
    TextRect.center = (x, y)
    screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

def text_objects(text, font, color):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, color)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def eating_apple():
    global scoreval, apple_spawn
    scoreval += 1
    apple_spawn = False

def spawnApple():
    global apple_pos, apple_spawn
    apple_pos = [random.randrange(1,60)*10, random.randrange(1,60)*10]
    apple_spawn = True

def score(score):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Score: "+str(score), True, WHITE)
    screen.blit(text,(10,10))

def main():
    global update, direction, run, snake_pos, snake_speed, apple_spawn, apple_pos
    pygame.time.delay(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        update = LEFT
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        update = RIGHT
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        update = UP
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        update = DOWN

    if update == RIGHT and direction != LEFT:
        direction = RIGHT
    if update == LEFT and direction != RIGHT:
        direction = LEFT
    if update == UP and direction != DOWN:
        direction = UP
    if update == DOWN and direction != UP:
        direction = DOWN

    if direction == RIGHT:
        snake_pos[0] += snake_speed
    if direction == LEFT:
        snake_pos[0] -= snake_speed
    if direction == UP:
        snake_pos[1] -= snake_speed
    if direction == DOWN:
        snake_pos[1] += snake_speed

    snake_body.insert(0, list(snake_pos))
    if pygame.Rect(*snake_pos, 20, 20).colliderect(*apple_pos, 20, 20):
        eating_apple()
    else:
        snake_body.pop()
    if not apple_spawn:
        spawnApple()

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    for pos in snake_body:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 20, 20))

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, pygame.Rect(apple_pos[0], apple_pos[1], 20, 20))

    if snake_pos[0] < 0 or snake_pos[0] > screen_width-20:
        run = False
    if snake_pos[1] < 0 or snake_pos[1] > screen_height-20:
        run = False

    for block in snake_body[1:]:
        if snake_pos[0] == block[0] and snake_pos[1] == block[1]:
            run = False

    score(scoreval)
    pygame.display.update()
    fps_controller.tick(25)

#main loop
run = True
while run:
    main()


game_over()
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've 2 functions `main()` and `game_over()`, each has its own event loop and does its own drawing.
Create 2 state variables. The first state (`run`), indicates if the game has to be continued or be terminated.
The 2nd state `gameover` indicates weather the game is in "game over" state or "game running" state.
Dependent on the state of `gameover`, either `main()` or `game_over()` has to be called continuouslyin the main loop. Both functions can change the states and have to return the current values of the state variables.
If the `gameover` changes from `True` to `False`, the the the game control variables have to be set to its initial state (Of course you can write a function for this in your code, too):

```py
run = True
gameover = False
while run:
    if not gameover:
        run, gameover = main()
    else:
        run, gameover = game_over()
        if not gameover:
            snake_pos = [100, 100]
            snake_body = [[100, 100], [90, 100], [80, 100]]
            snake_speed = 10
            apple_pos = [random.randrange(1,60)*10, random.randrange(1,60)*10]
            apple_spawn = True
            direction = RIGHT
            update = direction
            scoreval = 0
```

The game over function has to draw the "game over" screen and of course `pygame.display.update()`. The function evaluates the state changes and returns the the vales:

```py
def game_over():

    screen.fill(LIGHTBLUE)
    draw_text("GAME OVER", 48, WHITE, screen_width/2, screen_height/4)
    draw_text("Score: " + str(score), 22, WHITE,  screen_width / 2, screen_height / 3)
    draw_text("Press SPACE to play again or ESC to exit", 22, WHITE, screen_width/2, screen_height / 4)
    pygame.display.update()
    fps_controller.tick(25)

    rungame = True 
    continuegame = False 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            rungame  = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                continuegame = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                rungame = False
    return rungame, not continuegame
```

If the snake collides, then `main` returns a changed state:

```py
def main():
    global update, direction, snake_pos, snake_speed, apple_spawn, apple_pos
    pygame.time.delay(60)

    rungame = True
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            rungame = False

    # [...]

    collision = False
    if snake_pos[0] < 0 or snake_pos[0] > screen_width-20:
        collision = True
    if snake_pos[1] < 0 or snake_pos[1] > screen_height-20:
        collision = True

    for block in snake_body[1:]:
        if snake_pos[0] == block[0] and snake_pos[1] == block[1]:
            collision = True

    score(scoreval)
    pygame.display.update()
    fps_controller.tick(25)

    return rungame, collision
```

Comment: I've made the changes listed yet now I am receiving the following error

run, gameover = main()

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Comment: I got it. I made some simple changes to my previous code, realizing that the pygame.display.update() was my error. By doing that and resetting the snake position in the game_over() function it works perfectly. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your main loop inside another loop, so it will start again once the `game_over` function is done:

```
# main loop
while True:
    run = True
    while run:
        main()

    game_over()
```

Because `pygame.quit()` does not exit the program, you will need to instead have both loops being `while run:` and having two `run = True`s, or use a `sys.exit(0)` or `raise SystemExit(0)` after `pygame.quit()`.

You must also remove `return run` from the `for` loop in the `game_over()` function.

Comment: *"This is assuming that `pygame.quit()` exits the program, which I don't think"* - this is not a guess game. [`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) uninitialize all pygame modules. Every following call to any pygame instruction will immediatly cause a crash of the application!

Comment: @Rabbid76 That's not a quit. That's a crash. Thanks for the clarification, though.

Comment: Sadly the extra loop does not do the trick, now when the snake reaches the end the game just lags out completely.

Comment: @NarutoAbidal Remove `return run` from your game. Over loop.

Comment: Where? if I have

while True:
    run = True
    while run:
        main()
        
        
    game_over()

Comment: @NarutoAbidal Inside the `game_over()` function.